# Description of the Pi's state when there is a Rainbow Screen during boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, ssh, boot-issues

**Does anyone have a succinct description of what the Rainbow Screen is and what is happening on the Pi when it is seen during boot** (Pi3_ModelB_v1.2)**?**

Is it possible to SSH, other otherwise connect, into the Pi when this screen is shown?

What is the purpose of the Rainbow Screen?

Answer (score 2):

The splash screen is shown before the kernel is booted, so you cannot ssh or do anything really. Take a look at [this description](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Coloured_splash_screen)

Comment: I have just manged to SSH into a Pi showing a Rainbow Screen so this can't be true!

Comment: Is it still displaying the rainbow screen? With rainbow screen, I mean the full-screen rainbow, not the rainbow square in the top right that is shown when voltage is low.

Comment: Yes full screen